# Complicated Result Distribution Database Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my database my users have preferences stored, of what percentage of music they like. So user Billy has the following preferences

```
id:1 user:Billy music_type:Jazz percentage:50%
id:2 user:Billy music_type:Punk percentage:25%
id:3 user:Billy music_type:Folk percentage:25%
```

I also have a table that has 1 million jazz,punk and folk music tracks in it

```
id:1 music_type:Jazz track_name:Bippity Boop
id:2 music_type:Punk track_name:Grrrrrrrrrr!
id:3 music_type:Folk track_name:DeDiDoDeeDoo
```

I want to show Billy 100 tracks. 50 of them Jazz, 25 Punk, 25 Folk ( as per his preferences stored in the first table ).

How can I construct such a query from the database? ***Note***: This is obviously a vastly simplified version of my real tables and data, but any help will certainly help me solve my real problem.

Comment: how should the results be sorted?

Comment: by the id of the second table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With Postgresql 8.4 or higher, you could use a window function to partition the tracks by music type, get a per-partition counter, and then use it to limit the results per-partition according to the preferences.
Here is an SQL skeleton:

```
  select s.track_name,s.id from
   (select id, track_name, music_type, row_number() over (partition by music_type) as r
      from tracks ) s,
    preferences p
    where username='Billy'
    and p.music_type=s.music_type
    and s.r<=p.percentage
    order by s.id
```

Comment: is that possible with mysql too?